# How to make dynamic changes in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to add to a variable every time someone clicks a button on my website. I am very new to HMTL so I don't know how to do this. All the examples I've googled just change text into other text and not adding to a variable.

If someone would like to enlighten me on how to do this I would greatly apricate it.

```js
 
 function changeIt() {
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = "<h2>Congrats</h2>";
  }
```

```html
<div id="test">
   <b> <var> Test </ var> </b>
</div> 

<button onclick="changeIt()">Test</button>
```

Comment: show us what you have  tried?

Comment: Additional code should be included in the quesstion; it's very difficult to read in comments.

Comment: To add to a variable first you would get or retrieve the current text and then you would append to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've written in `document.innerHTML` is correct. For making it dynamic and to add a new `Congrats` onto the screen instead of just modifying the old one, you need to keep a global counter and loop over it.

```
let count = 0;
function changeIt() {
   count++;
   for (let i=0;i<count;i++) {
      document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = '';
      let h2 = document.getElementById('test').createElement;
      h2.innerHTML = "Congrats";
      document.getElementById('test').appendChild(h2);
   }
}
```

Since you are calling the `changeIt` function on every button click it will let you update the count and will loop over the count to add the `Congrats` 'count' number of times to your div.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var sum = 0;

function changeIt() {
    sum++;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = `<h2> ${sum} </h2>`;
    
  }
```

```html
<div id="test">
   <b> <var> Test </ var> </b>
</div> 

<button onclick="changeIt()">Test</button>
```